# MP3 files transfer to android through USB

Tags: java, android, file-transfer

I have created a PC application using java where I manipulate MP3 files. I want to now transfer these files into the android phone through usb from my application.

I would really appreciate if someone could write me some keywords so I could start looking into.

So far 
- I have come across "adb push"
- and some wireless and bluetooth (Not relevant to me since I am looking into USB)
- I watched some youtube videos of how its done manually just like an external memory, You copy and paste the music folder into the android memory card I think.

So I am only looking for the key APIs or something to start reading on. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no APIs for `pc - phone` communication via usb, your best option is adb.

Comment: I read about it and it mentions a lot about servers and ports. Got slightly confused but I guess I will learn more about it. It should be something like jdbc is for database ? I am quite new to android btw

Comment: @AschileMujadidi you only need the adb drivers for your phone, turn on usb-debbuging in settings, and then do `adb push` to `/sdcard` directory, or you can google on how to automount your sdcard. Btw i'm assuming your doing this for personal use and not publishing the app.

Comment: well, right now I don't even have an android phone and I am mainly relying on the emulator. But I should get one soon. I don't have any intention of actually publishing the app. but I would want ideally to make it as realistic and publishable as possible. Would there be an issue with adb if it was to publish ? Thank you

Comment: @AschileMujadidi the problem is adb itself. Do a search here on SO for `adb`, you'll see that alot of people experience problems with it. basically I wouldn't say its stable enough to publish an app with. Also alot of android phones don't come with the adb drivers, you'll need to provide a tutorial for your clients on how to install said drivers. All these will interfere with the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

My Android is configured to auto mount just like any other removable media. For me, putting music on it is a matter of a simple *cp* command on Linux.

Comment: Thats what I thought initially as well, to copy files just as if I am copying them into another drive (except that its external drive) but then thought there might be a better way of doing it. Specially if I want to use my app connect with different devices with possibly different removable media "name" ?